# Failed to Install New Kernel (v4.2.0-41.48) from (v4.2.0-38.45)

Tags: 14.04, apt, upgrade, kernel, initramfs

I tried to upgrade to the new kernel today, but DPKG half-configured the packages. Here's what APT said:

```
(Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 292462 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-4.2.0-41-generic_4.2.0-41.48~14.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Done.
Unpacking linux-image-4.2.0-41-generic (4.2.0-41.48~14.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-image-extra-4.2.0-41-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-extra-4.2.0-41-generic_4.2.0-41.48~14.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-extra-4.2.0-41-generic (4.2.0-41.48~14.04.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../linux-generic-lts-wily_4.2.0.41.33_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-generic-lts-wily (4.2.0.41.33) over (4.2.0.38.31) ...
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-generic-lts-wily_4.2.0.41.33_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-generic-lts-wily (4.2.0.41.33) over (4.2.0.38.31) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-4.2.0-41.
Preparing to unpack .../linux-headers-4.2.0-41_4.2.0-41.48~14.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-4.2.0-41 (4.2.0-41.48~14.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-4.2.0-41-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../linux-headers-4.2.0-41-generic_4.2.0-41.48~14.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-4.2.0-41-generic (4.2.0-41.48~14.04.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../linux-headers-generic-lts-wily_4.2.0.41.33_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-generic-lts-wily (4.2.0.41.33) over (4.2.0.38.31) ...
Preparing to unpack .../linux-libc-dev_3.13.0-91.138_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-libc-dev:amd64 (3.13.0-91.138) over (3.13.0-88.135) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.13-1) ...
Processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:i386 (2.40.2-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:amd64 (2.40.2-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+14.04.20140409-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1.1) ...
Setting up linux-image-4.2.0-41-generic (4.2.0-41.48~14.04.1) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.2.0-41-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-41-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.2.0-41-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-41-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.2.0-41-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-41-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-41-generic
WARNING: no ldd around - install libc-bin
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-41-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.2.0-41-generic.postinst line 1025.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.2.0-41-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Setting up geary (0.11.1~trusty1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-extra-4.2.0-41-generic:
 linux-image-extra-4.2.0-41-generic depends on linux-image-4.2.0-41-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-4.2.0-41-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.2.0-41-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic-lts-wily:
 linux-image-generic-lts-wily depends on linux-image-4.2.0-41-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-4.2.0-41-generic is not configured yet.
 linux-image-generic-lts-wily depends on linux-image-extra-4.2.0-41-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-extra-4.2.0-41-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-generic-lts-wily (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up linux-headers-4.2.0-41 (4.2.0-41.48~14.04.1) ...
Setting up linux-headers-4.2.0-41-generic (4.2.0-41.48~14.04.1) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms 4.2.0-41-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-41-generic
Setting up linux-headers-generic-lts-wily (4.2.0.41.33) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic-lts-wily:
 linux-generic-lts-wily depends on linux-image-generic-lts-wily (= 4.2.0.41.33); however:
  Package linux-image-generic-lts-wily is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-generic-lts-wily (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up linux-libc-dev:amd64 (3.13.0-91.138) ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I fixed it. The trick was to reinstall libc-bin, and then APT would automatically reconfigure those packages, and everything would be fine.